# Internet Explorer Internet Failure HTTP Status Codes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I usually translate `request.status == 0` as being a connection failure.

However, I have found that Internet Explorer sometimes uses HTTP 12007.

What would you recommend be the rules I use when deciding whether to tell the user "Internet Failure" vs just telling them "HTTP Status Code x"?

Is 12007 the only code for this sort of thing? (besides zero)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`status` values above 12000 come from Windows and tell you, that the HTTP request itself failed (ie. there never was a request).

You can find a list of these error messages [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383770%28VS.85%29.aspx).